# Can jackson ObjectMapper convert static and final fields of the class?

Tags: java, json, jackson

for example, if I have class A

```
public class A {
    public static final String STR_VAL = "some value";
    public String message = "some message";

    // getters and setters...
}
```

if I send this class to some spring webClient like
`webClient.postForObject(new A());`

is jackson converting all the fields?
what will be the actual JSON?

Comment: Why not trying by yourself ? There is no issue here.. and probably no research

Comment: I guess it would take less time to try then to ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson won't convert static fields out-of-the-box. Your JSON result will be:

```
{"message":"some message"}
```